# Saving value in "$data" from AJAX output

Tags: php, ajax

just wondering how i save the value from the "var vname" to "$data" so that i can use the value in my php. Assuming this is pretty easy, but i'm new to this :P

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        //Call the yourAjaxCall() function every 1000 millisecond
        setInterval("yourAjaxCall()",1000);
        function yourAjaxCall() 
      {
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
          data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                           //for example "id=5&parent=6"
          dataType: 'json',                //data format
          success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
          {
            var id = data[0];              //get id
            var vname = data[1];           //get name

            $data = vname; //HOW AND WHERE??????? :P
          }

        });
      };
</script>

/EDIT - want my var vname which is a color, to be placed in the style.
<body>
<div id="kvadrat1" style="width:200px; height:200px; position:relative; background-color:'HERE I WANT MY VALUE'">
</div>
```

Greatful for quick answers! :)

Comment: what do you really want to happen? you can't assign javascript variables to php especially when you did ajax.

Comment: In some way I want the "var name" to be saved as "$data". I dont know where in the code or how, so would be nice if someone explained it :)

Comment: $("#kvadrat1").css("backgorund-color",vname); you can use this in success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like you're just trying to fetch a name and an ID, but can't imagine why you'd need to do that every 1000 milliseconds - just seems like a lot of requests for data that isn't going to change?

Personally I'd just suggest making the API call in your PHP before the page loads and you can `var name = "<?=echo $name?>";` as avalkab has said in order to access the variables in JavaScript after the page has been loaded.

Should be able to use

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("api.php?id=5&parent=6")); // Specify or build query however you intended
```

If you are waiting for the user to interact (onclick or something) to call your javascript then if you expect to use data retrieved by AJAX to change data on the whole page - you might just want to reload the page, or revise your AJAX to make use of the data returned?

EDIT:
Since you are trying to change a colour you can simply use this line with jQuery

```
$("#kvadrat1").css({"background-color": vname});
```

So your code would be like so:

```
//Call the yourAjaxCall() function every 1000 millisecond
setInterval("yourAjaxCall()",1000);
function yourAjaxCall() {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
        data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
        dataType: 'json',                //data format
        success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
        {
            var id = data[0];              //get id
            var vname = data[1];           //get name

            $("#kvadrat1").css({"background-color" : vname});
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Well my database is updated frequently and this is just a simple example, every 1000 milliseconds isn't needed. The "var vname" is a variable that will change and I will use it in an animation. Therefore the page cannot reload, just the values, with ajax function

Comment: Thanks alot! Well, this is just an example, but it works atleast!

Comment: No problem, the syntax `$([STYLE])` grabs all elements that match the css style specified on the page, read up on jQuery usage here: http://jquery.com and the jQuery API here: http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Take a read here : [Pass javascript variable to php with ajax and the result doesn't show anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434482/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-with-ajax-and-the-result-doesnt-show-anything)

This will explain you to use javascript varaiables with PHP. Great answer from Zladuric.

Comment: Well he is returning the data in a div and I know how to do that. But then saving the output data to "$data" i don't understand. Need a simple explanation :)

Comment: He is getting the data with a GET function in PHP, look:

`echo $_GET['var_PHP_data'];` came from the AJAX call: `data: { var_PHP_data: var_data },`

Answer (score 0):

You can not save it in php.

You can save it to HTML element

If you need it in php variable send it to other page using ajax or header redirection

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is executed **once** when a page is loaded by the user. JS is executed while the user is on the page. This is why it is impossible to bind values generated by JS to PHP variables.

Answer (score 0):

> You cant use php code when page loaded or in js.
>
> javascript works only browser base. php works only server before
>   loading page.

```
// you can
var name = "<?=echo $name?>";

//you CANT!
var name = "joe";

$name = name;
```

Comment: Made it a bit clearer, thanks! I updated my question and you can se where i want to use my variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can not store it in php rather than you can use any html element to store it

you can keep data in html element by using `$("#id").html(data[0]);`